# Android Support library classes compilation error from different cordova plugins

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I am making a cordova app with Salesforce SDK. When I am trying to build the app in Android studio, I am getting compilation error from multiple plugins. Below are the list of plugins I have added-

```
call-number 1.0.4 "Cordova Call Number Plugin"
com.salesforce 7.2.0 "SalesforceMobileSDK Plugins"
cordova-android-support-gradle-release 3.0.1 "cordova-android-support-gradle-release"
cordova-plugin-app-version 0.1.9 "AppVersion"
cordova-plugin-camera 4.1.0 "Camera"
cordova-plugin-datepicker 0.9.3 "DatePicker"
cordova-plugin-device 2.0.3 "Device"
cordova-plugin-dialogs 2.0.2 "Notification"
cordova-plugin-document-viewer 0.9.11 "SitewaertsDocumentViewer"
cordova-plugin-email-composer 0.9.2 "EmailComposer"
cordova-plugin-file 6.0.2 "File"
cordova-plugin-filechooser 1.2.0 "File Chooser"
cordova-plugin-geolocation 4.0.2 "Geolocation"
cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0 "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard"
cordova-plugin-network-information 2.0.2 "Network Information"
cordova-plugin-screen-orientation 3.0.2 "Screen Orientation"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 5.0.3 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.4.3 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.4 "Whitelist"
cordova-plugin-x-toast 2.7.2 "Toast"
cordova-support-google-services 1.1.0 "cordova-support-google-services"
cordova.plugins.diagnostic 5.0.0 "Diagnostic"
es6-promise-plugin 4.2.2 "Promise"
phonegap-plugin-multidex 1.0.0 "Multidex"
phonegap-plugin-push 2.2.3 "PushPlugin"
```

Error from `> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac`

```
xyz\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\com\adobe\phonegap\push\BackgroundActionButtonHandler.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
import android.support.v4.app.RemoteInput;
                             ^
  symbol:   class RemoteInput
  location: package android.support.v4.app
xyz\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\com\adobe\phonegap\push\FCMService.java:26: error: cannot find symbol
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
                             ^
  symbol:   class NotificationCompat
  location: package android.support.v4.app

xyz\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\cordova\plugins\Diagnostic.java:57: error: cannot find symbol
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
                             ^
  symbol:   class ActivityCompat
  location: package android.support.v4.app
    xyz\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\cordova\plugins\Diagnostic_External_Storage.java:28: error: cannot find symbol
import android.support.v4.os.EnvironmentCompat;
                            ^
 symbol:   class EnvironmentCompat
 location: package android.support.v4.os
```

Similar errors from `cordova-plugin-email-composer, cordova-plugin-camera, cordova-plugin-document-viewer`

Even I tried `cordova-android-support-gradle-release` for resolving these android support library version issues, **no success**.

Also I tried to change the imports to `androidx...` packages by manually editing the classes, still my app is **not working**.

As I need all these plugins, I am not able to find how to resolve these errors.

```
cordova-cli:9.0.0
cordova-android: 8.0.0
```

Can someone please help me here.

Comment: Finally, this way it worked -
Added plugin `cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter` which helps is moving all the android support packages to androidx packages
And the android build is success now.

Comment: put your approach as an answer, it is really helpfull

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this by installing [`cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter`](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter) plugin. This plugin migrates all the legacy Android support references to the AndroidX versions.

If the project uses cordova-android@8, please enable AndroidX by adding below in `/platforms/android/gradle.properties`

```
 android.useAndroidX=true 
 android.enableJetifier=true
```

Support for AndroidX has been added in cordova-android@9

Comment: Thanks for this! I also found that the whitelist plugin is not yet compatible with the AndroidX changes, so I had to remove it in order to build. I'm guessing a new version is in the works?